# Return Email Signature Format

Tags: css, email, formatting, signature

I've created an email signature for gmail/mac-mail-app using tables and inline css, and for the best part works perfectly. I'm just having one issue which I'm not sure how best to solve:

My signature contains my logo, my details, and some social media icons. The problem is this: every now and again I will receive and email reply, which includes my signature from the original mail, and the size of the social media icon's no longer respect the sizes assigned to them in the original html code. Instead of being contained in the coded height=11, width=11 parameters, they are returned to me using the actual size of the icon stored on the server, which is at least two times larger than this.

The same happens if I copy and paste my signature in a mail, but is only apparent once the mail has been sent out.

The bizarre thing for me, is that my logo is not affected at all.

Original signature layout:

```
  -----------------------------------------------
 |       |name  /  icon_11px icon_11px icon_11px |
 | logo  |tel: 12 34 56                          |
 |       |email: email@gmail.com                 |
  -----------------------------------------------
```

returned or copy/paste signature layout:

```
  -----------------------------------------------
 |       |name  /  icon_32px icon_32px icon_32px |
 | logo  |tel: 12 34 56                          |
 |       |email: email@gmail.com                 |
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Obviously, the line hight is affected with the larger icons too, and it just looks a mess.

Any help on how to prevent this from happening would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Yet another question from me unanswered? Seriously.